# Keep getting Manifest Tasks does not support the manifestOutputFile property any more, please use the manifestOutputDirectory instead.

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After 2 months i reopened a project that needs to be updated but i keep getting this error:

Gradle sync failed: Manifest Tasks does not support the manifestOutputFile property any more, please use the manifestOutputDirectory instead.
            For more information, please check https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

And I use Gradle:3.0.1

This is app gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.sentry.android.gradle'

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven' }
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/tbruyelle/tbruyelle" }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        google()
    }}

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'user'
            keyPassword 'pas'
            storeFile file('../extra/file.jks')
            storePassword 'pass'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.go"
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 19
        versionName "1.2.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    productFlavors {
        // Define separate dev and prod product flavors.
        prod {
            // The actual minSdkVersion for the application.
            minSdkVersion 19
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions "default"

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':sweet_alert_dialog')

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.helpshift:android-aar:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    compile 'pl.charmas.android:android-reactive-location:0.9@aar'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.5'
    compile 'com.dlazaro66.wheelindicatorview:WheelIndicatorView:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.minimize.library:seekbar-compat:0.2.3'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.0.2'
    compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    compile 'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions:rxpermissions:0.8.0@aar'
    compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.4.1'
    compile 'com.braintreepayments:card-form:3.0.1'
    compile 'io.smooch:core:5.7.1'
    compile 'io.smooch:ui:5.7.1'
    compile 'us.belka:androidtoggleswitch:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.yasevich:endless-recycler-view:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
    compile 'de.cketti.mailto:email-intent-builder:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0'
    compile 'com.github.jrvansuita:CheckNewAppVersionAvailable:v1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.2.0'
    compile 'io.sentry:sentry-android:1.2.0'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.2'
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.2'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
apply plugin: 'io.sentry.android.gradle'
```

This was causing the error, removing it solved it.